# Prove that $e^{\frac{1}{n}} \le 1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}$

Tags: limits, analysis

How to prove that:

$$e^{\frac{1}{n}} \le 1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}$$

where $n\in\mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$.

I can't seem to find any connection from description after limit and this equation.

This is part of the following equation proving limit of $\frac{e^{x} - 1}{x} = 1$ for $x \xrightarrow{}0$:

[image]

Source: [https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~halas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ehalas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf) page 78

Comment: The proof uses the fact that the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{m})^{m+1}$ approaches $e$ from above, while $(1+\frac{1}{m})^m$ approaches it from below.

Comment: The text forms the *proof* that $\frac{e^x-1}{x} \to 0$. It's *not* supposed to use it.

Comment: @AdamRubinson yes thanks, I've updated condition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I don't get it. Text shows that limit is 1 as x approaches 0

Comment: Right, I had a typo. It should approach 1 instead.

Comment: What is the definition of $e$ you are working from? $\sum_k \frac{1}{k!}$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1+1/n\right)^n\ ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am familiar with both approaches, but I guess there will be connection to second one (as it looks similar), just not sure how to connect it to prove this inequality.

Comment: @AdamRubinson https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~halas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf - page 47 (pdf page 55)

Comment: $$e^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+ \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2!}\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{n^3}+...$$
$$1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}=\frac{n}{n - 1}=\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{n}}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+...$$
$$e^{\frac{1}{n}}-\Big(1 + \frac{1}{n - 1}\Big)=\Big(\frac{1}{2!}-1\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{3!}-1\Big)+\Big(\frac{1}{4!}-1\Big)+...<0$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $\frac{1}{n - 1} \geq e^\frac{1}{n} - 1, for~n \gt 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490942/show-frac1n-1-geq-e-frac1n-1-forn-gt-1) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24e%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%20%5Cle%201%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%20-%201%7D%24&p=1). There's also the more general case for any real $x \gt 1$ in [$e^{\frac{1}{x}} < 1 + \frac{1}{x-1} $](/q/3149211).

Comment: This is the Taylor's series $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...$